# use typescript generics from vanilla javascript in vscode extension

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am creating a VSCode extension using JavaScript, and building a custom `TextDocumentContentProvider` which needs to have a particular signature, but described in TypeScript. It's `onDidChange` member must be of type `Event<Uri>`, which of course uses *generics*. Documentation about TextDocumentContentProvider can be found here: https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#_a-nametextdocumentcontentprovideraspan-classcodeitem-id436textdocumentcontentproviderspan

Of course in "vanilla" JavaScript, there is no such thing as generics. What is the correct thing to return in JavaScript to meet the correct signature described in TypeScript?

This is my implementation so far:

```
function PostWindow() {
    this.onDidChange = ????;

    this.provideTextDocumentContent = function(uri) {
        return "test content";
    }
}

exports.PostWindow = PostWindow;
```

Comment: You could write some demo code in TS which uses this API and look what TSC generated from that.

Comment: Thanks @MikeLischke, that worked. I took a working TS example and looked at the output JS that vscode compiled. I created something like this and it worked great: https://gist.github.com/kindohm/83070f1a6f8e0055937a2a40c158fef5

Comment: I guess I can post my comment as answer then :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use TSC to convert TS code to JS to see how you can implement that.